# Creating N by N diagonal matrix using basic logic

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

I want to create a matrix of size N by N where N is a constant value defined globally, for now I just want to create a matrix where N=6. Where I fall short is I want to make it diagonally, like so:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 1 0 1 2 3
3 2 1 0 1 2
4 3 2 1 0 1
5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Currently I have this method:

```
public static void drawMatrix(){
    for (int line = 0; line < N; line++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's only able to print 0 1 2 3 4 5 in every line, so I suppose I need another nested for-loop, however I'm not sure how to set it up.

Comment: You already have two loops, maybe you'll see it clearer if you rename `j` as `column`. The value you put in each cell is the absolute (positive) difference beween row and column.

Comment: @SJuan76 is right.OP should check program flow especially in case of loops manually to find the mistake in his logic

Comment: After reading @SJuan76's comment I changed the print statement to "print(Math.abs(line-column) + " ") and this now produces the correct output. dasblinkenlight is also right in his solution, though the previously mentioned solution seems briefer and more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`j` is the column number, so it will be the same for all rows. What you need to do is to add or subtract `j` from the line number, depending on the line number, in order to make a "shift". Since the result could become negative, you will need to add `N` and *mod* by `N`:

```
if (j > line) {
    System.out.print((N-line+j)%N + " ");
} else {
    System.out.print((line-j+N)%N + " ");
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/IlkvQr)

You can also rewrite it without an `if` using a conditional expression:

```
int sign = j > line ? -1 : 1;
System.out.print((N+sign*(line-j))%N + " ");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/f7r9cr)

Comment: Or just the absolute value (not sure if this is the term for `Math.abs`) of line - column ;) to let the condition to the Math function.

Answer (score 6):

A little change in your code works

```
public static void drawMatrix() {
    for(int line = 0; line < N; line++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        System.out.print(Math.abs(line - j) + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like  :

```
    int n=6;

    for(int row=0;row<n;row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0;col<n;col++)
        {
         System.out.print(abs(col-row) +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

assuming you can use abs(). 
I hoped that help your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This also works :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 6;
    int column = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (column = row; column >= 0; column--) //prints till row number reaches 0
            System.out.print(column + " ");
        for (column = 1; column < N - row; column++)//from 1 to  N-row
            System.out.print(column + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```